# segmentation fault, c programm

Tags: c, for-loop, c-strings, palindrome, function-definition

I had to write a program in `c` as a homework assignment.  The program checks if the inputed string is a palindrome. Unfortunately I am getting a segmentation fault error when executing my program.

According to my knowledge segmentation fault means I am accessing memory that does not belong to me.

After some trying I found out, that I get that error "during" the marked `scanf` function. Please help.

This is the source-code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE !FALSE

#define STR_LEN01 1000

unsigned long long fStrLen(unsigned char str[])
{
    unsigned long long strLEN = 0;
    for (unsigned short i = 0; str[i++]; strLEN++) {}
    return strLEN;
}

unsigned short fStrComp(unsigned char str01[], unsigned char str02[])
{
    for (unsigned short i = 0; /* EMPTY */ ; i++)
    {
        if ( str01[i] == 0 && str02[i] == 0 ) 
            { return 0; }
        else if ( str01[i] != str02[i] && str02[i] == 0 ) 
            { return 1; }
        else if ( str01[i] != str02[i] && str01[i] == 0 ) 
            { return 2; }
        else if ( str01[i] != str02[i] && str02[i] != 0 && str01[i] != 0) 
            { return 3; }
    }
}
// ret 0 = strings are equal
// ret 1 = string 1 is longer
// ret 2 = string 2 is longer
// ret 3 = strings are not equal

void fStrRev(unsigned char str[])
{
    unsigned short len = fStrLen(str);
    unsigned char helpi, helpj;

    for (unsigned short i = len-1, j = 0; i >= 0; i--, j++)
    {
        helpi = str[i];
        helpj = str[j];

        str[i] = helpj;
        str[j] = helpi;

    }

} // ATTENTION! Inputted string will be reversed!

unsigned short fPalindrome(unsigned char str[]) // TODO
{
    unsigned char rev[STR_LEN01];

    for (unsigned short i = 0; str[i]; i++)
    {
        rev[i] = str[i];
    }
    fStrRev(str);

    return fStrComp(str, rev);   
} 
// ret 0 = palindrome
// *ret 1 = string 1 is longer*
// *ret 2 = string 2 is longer*
// ret 3 = strings are not equal, so no palindrome

int main(void)
{
    unsigned short ret = 0;
    unsigned char strIN01[STR_LEN01], strREV01[STR_LEN01], exit[] = "end";

    while(TRUE)
    {
        printf("\n\n"
                "Your word: ");


        scanf(" %s", strIN01); ***// MARKED SCANF***


        for (unsigned short i = 0; strIN01[i]; i++) 
        { putchar( tolower( strIN01[i] ) ); }

        if(fStrComp(strIN01, exit) == 0) { return 0; }

        for (unsigned int i = 0; strIN01[i]; i++)
        {
            strREV01[i] = strIN01[i];
        }
        strREV01[ fStrLen(strIN01) ] = 0;
        fStrRev(strREV01);
        printf("word reversed: %s", strREV01);

        ret = fPalindrome(strIN01);

        if(ret == 0)
        {
            printf("Hurray! We have a palindrome :)\r\n");
        }
        else if(ret == 3)
        {
            printf("Unfortunately, your word is no palindrome :(\r\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is the Shell error:

```
    └─$ gcc -Wall palindrom.c -o pal -lm                                                                                
    └─$ ./pal                           


    Your word: hello    
    zsh: segmentation fault  ./pal

    └─$
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Yours Faithfully,
Tiger

PS The functions were tested by me separately while programming and should work

Comment: You should print a newline after each output, so the buffer is flushed. Then you'll know where in the program the error is happening.

Comment: Or call `fflush(stdout)`.

Comment: I don't know if this is the cause but is it possible that the input into `scanf` is larger than `strIN01`?

Comment: Whenever I run into a segfault, I compile with the `-g` option and run my program through valgrind.

Comment: Running in a debugger is invaluable in such cases. When you hit the segfault, the debugger will show you a stack trace. This often (though not always) points straight to the problem.

Comment: You're not adding null terminators in `fStrRev()` and `fPalindome()`.

Comment: `if(fStrComp(strIN01, exit) == 0)` is incorrect.  `exit` is not the string `"exit"`.  It is a function.  Try `if(fStrComp(strIN01, "exit") == 0)`

Comment: @William Pursell exit is a string, it contains "end" which is the given word to end the program

Comment: @WilliamPursell I'm pretty sure you can define a local variable (without external linkage) called `exit`, but you cannot define a function called `exit`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the for loop in **fStrRev** is what's causing you segmentation fault

```
for (unsigned short i = len-1, j = 0; i >= 0; i--, j++)
{
    helpi = str[i];
    helpj = str[j];

    str[i] = helpj;
    str[j] = helpi;
}
```

*i* gets decremented by one each cycle and the cycle continues until *i* is less than 0, the problem is that when *i* get decremented from 0 it becomes 65535 instead of -1 as *i* is an unsigned short causing the for loop to continue and your seg fault when it tries to access str[65535]
to fix this just change the for loop from **unsigned short** to **short** or another signed integer type if you need the extra range like so.

```
for (short i = len-1, j = 0; i >= 0; i--, j++)
{
    helpi = str[i];
    helpj = str[j];

    str[i] = helpj;
    str[j] = helpi;
}
```

There's also another problem with your code as it's not working as intended for reversing the word and reversing it twice, so the comparison should be changed from `i >= 0` to `i >= len/2` or what Ian Abbott commented if you're going with his solution

Comment: Alternatively: `for (unsigned short i = len - 1, j = 0; j < len; i--, j++)`. It works for zero-length strings too!

Comment: Although it is worth mentioning that this reverses the string twice, so it ends up the same as the original! The test should be `i > j`, but should not be used for zero-length strings.

Comment: FYI, your `fStrRev` does NOT reverse the string... or rather it does, but then it reverses it again to restore it to the original state. Your loop should be `for (short i = len - 1, j = 0; j < len / 2; i--, j++)`

Answer (score 2):

Within this function

```
unsigned short fPalindrome(unsigned char str[]) // TODO
{
    unsigned char rev[STR_LEN01];

    for (unsigned short i = 0; str[i]; i++)
    {
        rev[i] = str[i];
    }
    fStrRev(str);

    return fStrComp(str, rev);   
}
```

you are not building a string in the array `rev`. That is the array does not contain the zero terminating character `'\0'`.

So calling string functions for this array invokes undefined behavior.

You could rewrite the function at least the following way using a loop

```
unsigned short fPalindrome( unsigned char str[]) // TODO
{
    unsigned char rev[STR_LEN01];

    unsigned char *p = rev;

    while ( ( *p++ = *str++ ) != '\0' );

    fStrRev(str);

    return fStrComp(str, rev);   
}
```

Comment: @DanielWalker Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

The correct and this time really tested version of the fStrRev function is:

```
void fStrRev(unsigned char str[])
{
    unsigned long long len = 0;
    unsigned char help;

    for (; str[i++]; len++) {}

    if (len >= FALSE) 
    {
        printf("ERROR Line: %d, len = 0\r\n\r\n", __LINE__);
        exit(1);
    }

    for (unsigned short i = len-1, j = 0; i >= len/2; i--, j++)
    {
        help = str[i];
        str[i] = str[j];
        str[j] = help;
    } // no null terminator added because it is already there
      // because I reverse the string in place
} // ATTENTION! Inputted string will be reversed!
```

It only needs one help variable and it does not rely on other functions.

Note: This answer is by the author of the question.